# Issue getting specific events (via location) from Eventbrite API

Tags: javascript, api, events, eventbrite

Hi I'm having some issues displaying events from the Eventbrite API.
I have managed to return 50 events (which are the first 50 events that the API displays by default, with the locations ranging all over the world). I am attempting to return events to a specific location (in my case Stoke-on-trent) but the api returns the same 50 events no matter what parameters I put in my search query. 
I have put the code for this below.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var settings = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
// THIS IS WHAT SEARCHES FOR EVENTS  >>>>
"url": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Stoke-on-trent&location.within=10mi&expand=organizer,venue",
/*"url": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/52782578112/",*/
"method": "GET",
"headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer ***************",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into pagination. If you add `page=2` to the end of your URL and you will get the next page.

There are 6 pages for your specific call.

```
'pagination': {'has_more_items': True,
                'object_count': 283,
                'page_count': 6,
                'page_number': 1,
                'page_size': 50}}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm still running into the same problem, although I do get more results now

Comment: I missed this before. You need to change your header from “Content-Type: application/json” to “Accept: application/json” 

Content-Type is for POST and is expecting a Data Payload when there is none. This is breaking the parameters.

Comment: my god it actually works, thankyou so much! you're more useful than the actual Eventbrite developer team

Comment: Even with the continuation token attached, there are some pagination calls that need the page number as well. Found this with a call to `https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/<OrganizationId>/organizers/`, where the pagination token returns the same 50 results as the normal call. Thanks @NathanTinius!